mat-select show selection without selecting any mat-option
I'm using a custom built mat-select, where user adds a range of numbers and I need to show the selected ranges (or at least something) when dropdown is closed, but can't find an option for this.
This is my .html:
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mat-form-field-header-filter">
          <mat-label>Selecteer week</mat-label>
          <mat-select [formControl]="weekRangeSelect" [compareWith]="fakeWeekRange">
            <mat-select-trigger>asda</mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-option class="week-selector" (click)="$event.preventDefault()" disabled>
              <span>Van</span>
              <span class="input">
                <input matInput type="text" min="1" max="52" #weekFrom>
              </span>
              <span>tot</span>
              <span class="input">
                <input matInput type="text" min="1" max="52" #weekTo>
              </span>
              <span>week(s)</span>
              <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="addWeekRange()">Add</button>
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option class="week-warn" disabled *ngIf="weekInvalidRange">
              Invalid range provided!
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option class="week-warn" disabled *ngIf="weekAlreadyAddedRange">
              Range already added!
            </mat-option>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let weeks of selectedWeeks; let i = index">
              <mat-option class="week-remove-selector">
                <span>
                  {{ weeks.from }} - {{ weeks.to }}
                </span>
                <span>
                  <button mat-icon-button (click)="removeWeekRange(i)">
                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                  </button>
                </span>
              </mat-option>
            </ng-container>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

and this is my .ts:
  @ViewChild('weekFrom', {static: true}) weekFrom: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  @ViewChild('weekTo', {static: true}) weekTo: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

  public selectedWeeks: { from: number; to: number }[] = [];
  public weekInvalidRange: boolean = false;
  public weekAlreadyAddedRange: boolean = false;
  public weekRangeSelect: FormControl = new FormControl<string>('');

  addWeekRange(): void {
    const from: number = parseInt(this.weekFrom.nativeElement.value, 10),
      to: number = parseInt(this.weekTo.nativeElement.value, 10);
    let add: boolean = true;
    if (from !== null && to !== null && !isNaN(from) && !isNaN(to) && typeof from !== 'undefined' && typeof to !== 'undefined') {
      this.selectedWeeks.forEach((r: { from: number, to: number }): void => {
        if (from < 1 || to > 52 || from > to) {
          add = false;
          this.weekInvalidRange = true;
          setTimeout((): boolean => this.weekInvalidRange = false, 5000);
        } else if (from <= r.to && r.from <= to) {
          add = false;
          this.weekAlreadyAddedRange = true;
          setTimeout((): boolean => this.weekAlreadyAddedRange = false, 5000);
        }
      });
      if (add) {
        this.selectedWeeks.push({
          from: parseInt(this.weekFrom.nativeElement.value, 10),
          to: parseInt(this.weekTo.nativeElement.value, 10)
        });

        this.weekFrom.nativeElement.value = '';
        this.weekTo.nativeElement.value = '';
      }
    }
    this.selectedWeeks = this.selectedWeeks.sort((a, b) => a.from - b.from);
    this.weekRangeSelect.setValue(this.selectedWeeks.map(d => d.from + '-' + d.to).join(', '));
  }

  removeWeekRange(index: number): void {
    this.selectedWeeks.splice(index, 1);
    this.weekRangeSelect.setValue(this.selectedWeeks.map(d => d.from + '-' + d.to).join(', '));
  }

  fakeWeekRange(a, b): boolean {
    return this.selectedWeeks.length > 0;
  }

  formatSuspectDropdown(result: any): string {
    return result !== null && typeof result === 'object' ? result.name : result;
  }

But the mat-select still shows a placeholder when a week range were added and when the dropdown is closed.
How to show selected week ranges when user closes a dropdown?
Stacklitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-8dyqtv?file=src%2Fweek-picker%2Fweek-picker.component.ts

If you use a template reference variable in your mat-select, see the select="matSelect", this makes that "select" is the "matSelect" (not the FormControl)
<mat-select #select="matSelect" [formControl]="weekRangeSelect" 
     [compareWith]="fakeWeekRange">
    ...
</mat-select>

You can create, e.g. a card with the values and use select.panelOpen
  <!--only show if is not open and if has elements-->
  <mat-card *ngIf="!select.panelOpen &&
                   selectedWeeks?.length">
    <mat-card-content><div *ngFor="let weeks of selectedWeeks; let i = index">
      <span>
        {{ weeks.from }} - {{ weeks.to }}
      </span>
      <span>
        <!--note the $event.stopPropagation if you want not to open the select-->
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="$event.stopPropagation();
                                         removeWeekRange(i)">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>

Update using the "label" to show the range separated by commas
We can create a getter
  get label()
  {
    return this.selectedWeeks && this.selectedWeeks.length?
            this.selectedWeeks.map(d => d.from + '-' + d.to)
                    .join(', '):'Selecteer week'
  }

And then show the label only when close
  <mat-label>{{!select.panelOpen?label:''}}</mat-label>
  <mat-select #select="matSelect" [formControl]="weekRangeSelect" 
             [compareWith]="fakeWeekRange">
  ...
  </mat-select>

We can think about use a *ngIf in the way, but not work
  //this **NOT** work
  <mat-label *ngIf="select.panelOpen">{{label}}</mat-label>

the forked stackblitz

Not sure how this one would solve my problem. I didn't mention that I have a problem with showing the mat-option with selected week ranges, I have a problem with mat-select that even when I do populate it (through various options as a test), the placeholder stays as Selecteer week and is not changed to ranges added. I would like to show instead of Selecteer week this: 1-10, 20-29, ....

@KristjanO., sorry, I dind'nt know where you want to show the "range". I updated the answer and forked your stackblitz

Wow, nice solution and working! Thank you for your time and help!
